# Snakemake: use wildcard as pandas data.frame filter value

Tags: snakemake

I want to use a global wildcard (wildcard_constraints) as filter value for a pandas dataframe in order to build a set of inputs.

```
# I read the table
manifest = pd.read_csv(str(config["manifest"]),  sep='\t+', engine='python')   # target_id | input_id | broad

# Define a list of elements
SAMPLENAMES = list(numpy.unique(list(manifest.Sample_ID)))
CASENAMES = list(numpy.unique(list(manifest.Case_ID)))

# definition of global options
def constraint_to(values: List[str]) -> str:
    """
    From a list, return a regular expression allowing each
    value and not other.
    ex: ["a", "b", "v"] -> (a|b|v)
    """
    if isinstance(values, str):
            raise ValueError("constraint_to(): Expected a list, got str instead")
    return "({})".format("|".join(values))


wildcard_constraints:
    SAMPLE = constraint_to(SAMPLENAMES),
    CASE = constraint_to(CASENAMES)



# define the rule
rule rule_A:
    input:
        manifest = config["manifest"],
        token = config["token"],
        genome = ancient(config["genome_fasta"])
    output:
        bam = os.path.join((manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == "{SAMPLE}"].id).iloc[0], (manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == "{SAMPLE}"].filename).iloc[0]),
        bam_index = os.path.join((manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == "{SAMPLE}"].id).iloc[0], ''.join([re.sub(".bam", "", (manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == "{SAMPLE}"].filename).iloc[0], count=0, flags=0),".bai"]))
    params:
        sample = "{SAMPLE}"
    log:
        temp_gdc = temp(os.path.join("01_Mutec2_raw_VCF/log", "{SAMPLE}_temp_progress_gdc-client.log")),
        gdc = os.path.join("01_Mutec2_raw_VCF/log", "{SAMPLE}_gdc-client.log")
    threads:
        max(math.floor(workflow.cores/6), 1)
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/download_bam/download_bam---{SAMPLE}_benchmark.txt"
    priority: 100
    shell:
        """
        ...
        """
```

And I get the following error message:

```
IndexError in file xxx.snakefile, line 75:
single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

The wildcards work when I do not use them as filter values but just as part of a path for instance.

Do you have any idea?

I tried the following forms:

`bam = os.path.join((manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == "{SAMPLE}"].id).iloc[0], (manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == "{SAMPLE}"].filename).iloc[0])`

ERROR:

```
IndexError in file xxx.snakefile, line 75:
single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

#---------------

- `bam = os.path.join((manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == {SAMPLE}].id).iloc[0], (manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == {SAMPLE}].filename).iloc[0])`
- `bam = os.path.join((manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == str({SAMPLE})].id).iloc[0], (manifest[manifest['Sample_ID'] == str({SAMPLE})].filename).iloc[0])`

ERROR:

```
NameError in file XXX.snakefile, line 75:
name 'SAMPLE' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you share what works? Also could you expand on what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps a sample of manifest might help, or a simplified example.